# Samsung galaxy s3 app removal

Tags: applications

Can I uninstall a preloaded app I want to remove flip board but it pops up with a warning that it may cause problems with other apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply have Flipboard "Turned Off" in the Application Manager on my S3. I have no problems with other apps from turning this off.